# Why is the stacking of site elements under each other not working properly?

Tags: javascript, html, css

For my website I want to make a responsive design for stacking elements under each other. I made this work for the first section (class named withwithout1), but I can't make it work for the class named withwithout2. Keep in mind I want to keep the elements the same way I made them for the larger screen size option.

In short: How can I manage to place the elements under each other in the order I want them to (So text first than the image).

```css
/* Withwithout styling */
.withwithout {
    height:58rem;
    position: relative;
}

.withwithout1 {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns:repeat(2,minmax(0,1fr));
}

.withwithout1left {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 8rem;
}

.withwithout1left h4 {
    color: var(--color-withwithout);
}
.withwithout1left h2 {
    margin: 0.2rem 0rem 1rem;
}

.withwithout1right {
    text-align: center;
}

.withwithout1right img {
    max-width: 65%;
}

.withwithout2 {
    display: grid;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    position: relative;
    grid-template-columns:repeat(2,minmax(0,1fr));
}
.withwithout2left {
    text-align: center;
}

.withwithout2left img {
    max-width: 60%;
}
.withwithout2right {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 2rem;
}

.withwithout2right h4 {
    color: var(--color-withwithout);
}
.withwithout2right h2 {
    margin: 0.2rem 0rem 1rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1070px) {
    .startingbackground_div p {
        font-size: 0.93rem;
    }
    .startingbackground_div h1 {
        font-size: 2rem;
    }
    .startingbackground2_left h2 {
        font-size:1.59rem;
    }
    .startingbackground2_left p {
        font-size:0.93rem;
        width:100%;
        margin-left:3rem;
    }
    .withwithout1left h2{
        font-size: 1.75rem;
    }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 890px) {
    .nav_menu {
        display:none;
    }
    .login_nav {
        display:none;
    }
    .hamburger {
        display:flex;
    }
    .nav_container {
        padding-left: 0.3rem;
        margin-left: auto;
    }
    .startingbackground_container {
        display:block;
        margin-top: 9rem;
    }
    .startingbackground_div p {
        font-size: 1.1rem;
    }
    .startingbackground_div h1 {
        font-size: 2.8rem;
    }
    .startingbackground {
        height: 90vh;
    }
    .solutions {
        margin-top: 2rem;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    .solutions_right img {
        display:flex;
        margin:auto;
        margin-top:5rem;
        width:77%;
        height:auto;
    }
    .startingbackground2 {
        height:18rem;
    }
    
    .startingbackground2 h2 {
        margin-top: 4rem;
        font-size:1.04rem;
    }
    .startingbackground2 p {
        font-size:0.79rem;
    }

    .startingbackground2_right {
        margin-top:4.5rem;
        max-width: 70%;
    }
    .withwithout {
        height:100rem;
    }
    .withwithout1 {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .withwithout1left h2 {
        font-size:1.4rem;
    }
    .withwithout1right {
        max-width: 60%;
        margin-top: 3rem;
        margin-left: 7rem;
    }
    .withwithout2 {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .withwithout2right {
        margin-top:-35rem;
    }
    .withwithout2left {
        margin-top:16rem;
    }
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>DraftFlex</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 maximum-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        
        <!-- Font-families -->
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;500;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Animations -->
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/@lottiefiles/lottie-player@latest/dist/lottie-player.js"></script>
    
        <!-- Fontawesome Icon -->
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/98d94e81b6.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <!-- Iconscout CDN -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.0/css/line.css">
    </head>
  
  
  <section class="withwithout">
        <div class="container withwithout_container">
            <div class="withwithout1">
                <div class="withwithout1left">
                    <h4>Without Draftflex</h4>
                    <h2>Many tools can be required for the <br> draft-to-deal proces</h2>
                    <p>In many projects, all kinds of tools can be helpful. <br> However, the combination of these application is what <br> is desired. Using many different tools can interfere <br> with an easy workflow and may decrease efficiency <br> and productivity.</p>
                </div>

                <div class="withwithout1right">
                <img src="/Icons/replaces.png" alt="replaces">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="withwithout2">
              <div class="withwithout2left">
              <img src="/Icons/replaces2.png" alt="replaces2">
              </div>

              <div class="withwithout2right">
                <h4>Without Draftflex</h4>
                <h2>An integration of these tools is <br> what improves the workflow</h2>
                <p>By the use of DraftFlex, the combined <br> process of all these applications is used. <br> This helps boost the performance <br> and competence. An easy workflow is key <br> in every business, and this is what DraftFlex <br> stimulates. </p>
              </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Why are you displaying `withwithout1left` as inline-block?

Comment: I deleted it right now, thanks for pointing that out. The problem still persist though, do you have any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use separate divs instead of making them as nested divs.
then manage their positions

Comment: So then I shouldn't display it as grid?

Comment: first div contains it all divs so ur moving all divs after this moving sub divs again

Comment: My problem with making seperate divs is, I don't see how that would solve the problem since I want to make a reversed positioning with the class withwithout2. You see on larger screens the text of withwithout2 is positioned to the right of the image of withwithout2. This means that if placed under each other the image will be placed on top, but I want the text to be above the image there.

Comment: By using `order` with `display: flex` you can set the order of divs. Then you can reverse it by using `order` in the @media. Info on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order